# How to calculate Somer's D / C-index for an external validation dataset given a ordinal response

Tags: r, hmisc

I have fit a proportional odds regression model using the `lrm` function within Harrell's 'rms' package. I am wondering how I can calculate the c-index / Somer's D for an external validation dataset applied to my fitted model. These statistics can be calculated for the fitted model directly using fitted.model$stats, but I am unsure how to get them for an external validation dataset.

There appear to be built in function for doing this for a binary or survival responses in the 'rms' package, `val.prob` & `val.surv`, but I can't find the method for an ordinal response.

Comment: Perhaps you are aware of this, but the c-index is also known as the area under the receiver-operating characteristic curve, better known as the AUC. The technique typically used to create validation sets is called cross-validation. There are many examples of how to calculate the AUC from models using cross-validation on the web. Perhaps using these terms will make your search easier.

Comment: Thanks for your insight nograpes, I appreciate it. I have found the correlate() function within the 'mRMRe' package to be a useful solution,  using the linear predictor resulting from applying the validation dataset to my fitted model, as well as the observed ordinal response in the validation data.

Answer (score 1):

You should re-read the documentation for `lrm`. Ordinal responses are handled in that function. I run this code using the first example from ?lrm that generates a "fit"-object:

```
pred.logit <- predict(fit)
phat <- 1/(1+exp(-pred.logit))
> str(pred.logit)
 Named num [1:1000] NA NA NA 0.234 0.577 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:1000] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
> str(fit$y)
 Named num [1:997] 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:997] "4" "5" "6" "7" ...

val.prob(phat[-(1:3)], y=fit$y, m=20, cex=.5)

          Dxy       C (ROC)            R2             D      D:Chi-sq           D:p 
 2.836172e-01  6.418086e-01  8.959553e-02  6.840647e-02  6.920125e+01  1.110223e-16 
            U      U:Chi-sq           U:p             Q         Brier     Intercept 
-2.006018e-03 -1.591616e-12  1.000000e+00  7.041249e-02  2.315756e-01  5.977542e-14 
        Slope          Emax           S:z           S:p          Eavg 
 1.000000e+00  1.956213e-13 -3.813108e-02  9.695832e-01  2.443947e-02 
>
```